# Trend on 3D Printer Filament Costs?

Tags: trends, cost

Some have suggested that filament costs are asymptotically approaching a baseline cost - others that costs are linearly decreasing.

Does anyone know where to find the trending costs on a single class of filament over the past decade or more?